# g2o doesn't find its own functions in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I designed a ROS package that needs g2o library for SLAM.
I first tried to download and install it via shell, then I tried, as a test, to make some inclusions:

```
#include "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/types/slam2d/vertex_se2.h"
#include "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/types/slam2d/vertex_point_xy.h"
#include "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/types/slam2d/edge_se2.h"
#include "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/types/slam2d/edge_se2_pointxy.h"
#include "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/types/slam2d/types_slam2d.h"

#include "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/core/sparse_optimizer.h"
#include "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/core/block_solver.h"
#include "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/core/factory.h"
#include "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/core/optimization_algorithm_factory.h"
#include "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/core/optimization_algorithm_gauss_newton.h"
#include "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/g2o/solvers/csparse/linear_solver_csparse.h"
```

**rosmake** built without any issue the package, even when I added

```
using namespace g2o;
```

Then, I added a line of code that I actually need:

```
SparseOptimizer optimizer;
```

It gave origin to this error:

```
 CMakeFiles/thesis_main.dir/src/messageListener.o: In function `messageListener':
  /home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/thesis_pack/src/messageListener.cpp:36: undefined reference to `g2o::SparseOptimizer::SparseOptimizer()'
  CMakeFiles/thesis_main.dir/src/thesis_main.o: In function `~messageListener':
  /home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/thesis_pack/src/messageListener.h:44: undefined reference to `g2o::SparseOptimizer::~SparseOptimizer()'
```

As a second attempt, I downloaded **vslam** package from web, entered its subfolder */g2o* and from inside it I ran **build**.
As a consequence, ROS found a new package **g2o**, as shown by *rospack list*; then I updated the *manifest* file in my package:

```
<package>
  <description brief="thesis_pack">

     thesis_pack

  </description>
  <author>Biagio</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/thesis_pack</url>
  <depend package="roscpp"/>
  <depend package="rospy"/>
  <depend package="tf"/>
  <depend package="nav_msgs"/>
  <depend package="g2o"/>


</package>
```

leaving inclusions and g2o's namespace declaration in my .cpp file, but the error continues to remain.
Do you know how to solve the problem?

thanks for help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84746/g2o-doesn%27t-find-its-own-functions-in-ros/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend that you slow down in all your downloading and hacking and hard coding paths.  For example you should not be doing things like hard coding the full paths to include files as you example include above.

Also to make things easier to help you please copy and paste your actual commands you are running.  Because "build" as stated above is not a command that you can actually run.

Your "original" error is just a linking error, which means that you already had the package enough to compile against.  You need to use the cmake command target_link_libraries to make sure to link your executable or library against the g2o library.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2013-09-30**:
thanks for your answer. the procedure of entering vslam's subdirectory /g2o and running "build" was proposed by someone on the web who states to have solved my same problem. as a newbie, I trusted and tried to do the same.
regarding commands i used, not too much to say: after BUILD in vslam/g2o...

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2013-09-30**:
... I used rosmake in ROS' g2o package (with no error) and did the same in mine, getting the error i reported in post. i'm not feeling very confident with my installation of g2o as a ROS' package, so maybe i should use the library i installed by shell. how should i use  target_link_libraries?